# Can I find object into if conditional with thymeleaf

Tags: spring, java-stream, thymeleaf

I'm trying to search a table with user records. So, admin users are being able to delete but standard user not. The `user_role` relationship is many to many, so I don't know how can i access to this data in a foreach loop with thymeleaf.

This is the code:

```
                <tbody>
                    <tr th:each="user : ${users}">              
                        <td th:text="*{id}" class="text-center id-field"></td>
                        <td th:text="*{name}" class="text-center"></td>
                        <td th:text="*{email}" class="text-center"></td>
                        <td th:if ="${currentUser.id != user.id and !user.getRoles().stream().filter(r -> r.name.equals('ADMIN')).isEmpty()}" class="text-center d-flex justify-content-center align-items-center">
                            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" onclick="deleteUser(this)">Delete</button>
                        </td>
                    </tr>               
                </tbody>
```

As you can see, I'm trying to use a stream filter to find if user role is standard or admin.
Is throwing me this error:

```
 Expression [currentUser.id != user.id and !user.getRoles().stream().filter(r -> r.name.equals('ADMIN')).isEmpty()] @65: EL1042E: Problem parsing right operand
```

Is it possible what I'm trying?

Answer (score 1):

First things first:

```
!user.getRoles().stream().filter(r -> r.name.equals('ADMIN')).isEmpty()
```

This is not valid Java code, it wont compile. What you probably would want is the following:

```
!user.getRoles().stream().filter(r -> r.name.equals('ADMIN')).collect(Collectors.toList()).isEmpty()
```

Moreover, I don't think Thymeleaf supports streams at this point in time: https://github.com/thymeleaf/thymeleaf/issues/660

You would better do the iteration in a Java method and put the result on your `Model`.

Comment: Also `.collect()` call is not optimal, because there is a `.noneMatch()` method, like this: `user.getRoles().stream().noneMatch(r -> r.name.equals('ADMIN'))`

Comment: Finally I think it isn't possible, I'm still looking for a way to solve this. Because to iterate into users data in controller to pass them to the view is not optimal